# Execute Apex method avoiding required field validations - <Apex:Region> not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, post, order-of-execution

Here I want to insert one record on clicking "Post" button, at the same time I don't want to execute code in "First" pageblocksection (avoid all required fields).

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection id="First">
            //// HERE I HAVE SOME REQUIRED FIELDS 
  <apex:pageBlockSection>

// I Want to Execute following section without any Interference of above PageBlockSection- First
    <apex:pageBlockSection > 
           <apex:actionRegion immediate="true"> 
               <apex:selectList value="{!selectedID}" size="1" label="Select ">
                      <apex:selectOptions value="{!selected}"></apex:selectOptions>
               </apex:selectList>
               <apex:inputTextarea value="{!obj.Body}" label="Enter body : "/>
               <apex:commandButton value="Post" action="{!postMethod}"/>            
           </apex:actionRegion>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain actionRegion only applies when you are using the partial page refresh feature. What you have will post the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, and I'm flying free here without testing, but I'm pretty certain you need to also specify to rerender just the part of the page you want to post back. Otherwise the action will post the entire page anyway. So it should look something like this:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="First">
        //// HERE I HAVE SOME REQUIRED FIELDS 
<apex:pageBlockSection>

// I Want to Execute following section without any Interference of above PageBlockSection- First
<apex:pageBlockSection id="postBack" >  <----added an element Id
       <apex:actionRegion> 
           <apex:selectList value="{!selectedID}" size="1" label="Select ">
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!selected}"></apex:selectOptions>
           </apex:selectList>
           <apex:inputTextarea value="{!obj.Body}" label="Enter body : "/>
           <apex:commandButton reRender="postBack" value="Post" action="{!postMethod}"/>            
       </apex:actionRegion>             ^----added the rerender to refresh the 
    </apex:pageBlockSection>                 containing section
```

There are a couple of other things:

1. Your method you execute from the command button needs to be declared as `void`.
2. You might look into the `apex:actionStatus` tag so you can tell users that the page is working
3. You can point `reRender` to multiple element ID's. Just separate ID's by commas. `rerender="this,that,theOther"`. The one part of the UI you will want to refresh in addition to this section is your `apex:pageMessages` tag, so that any errors that occur can be surfaced to the user.

Also, setting `immediate="true"` actually will result in data not being posted to the server. So you don't want that in this instance. The use case for this feature is a cancel button...allowing you to cancel out of a page without validating data, or other post backs where there is no need for data to go from client to server in order to complete the request (paging to the next set of results in a list, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You should put commandbutton inside actionregion

CommandButton

or you can directly use immediate attribute in commandbutton.

Comment: I have commandbutton inside Action Region only.

Comment: Please add immediate attribute to commandbutton and if it still doesnt work. Please post full code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the trick,

I put that pageblock sections in different `<apex:Form> </apex:form>`

But I was hoping that ActionRegion will work for me.

Comment: Nilesh, this should really be a comment to your original post. This is not an answer.